# Store DXF line nodes

Tags: c#, dxf

first post here.
I am a CNC machine operator and i want to make a program that outputs code for my CNC machine (G-code).

What i am trying to understand is how i can put the start and en points of line`s inside my DXF file containing the geometry i want to machine, to some sort of list, so i can (hopefully) do some sweepline calculations with them.

I found al lot of information about how to read a DXF file, but i could not find how to store these points.

SO: how can i save a pair of line points (x1 y1 , x2 y2) to a list an calculate with them.

never mind my bad english

Answer (score 1):

In C# there is an object called a `List`.  You can store your points, as `Point` objects, in a list.

```
List<Point> myList = new List<Point>();
myList.Add(new Point(x1, y1));
```

and then continue using the `Add` method to add more points to your list.  You can retrieve the points from the list using a `foreach` loop or by index number.  The points are ordered in the list in the same order that you added them.